# How to set buttons according to different screen size

Tags: java, android, xml, button, layout

Hey guys please check my code i am not able to set buttons with different screen size,  i set buttons in xml but whenever i start app on 5.0 screen size it works very fine but whenever i open my app in 6.0 or more than that then it shows extra space in bottom, i tried every possible solution but still no solution. so please check my code and see screen shots and give me right solution for this.

[image]

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cool" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/attitude" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/love" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/broken" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/funnn"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sad"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the LinearLayouts, and you should create chains for every view. You'll have three different horizontal chains (one for each row):

- parent <--> `imageButton` <--> `imageButton1` <--> parent
- parent <--> `imageButton2` <--> `imageButton3` <--> parent
- parent <--> `imageButton4` <--> `imageButton5` <--> parent

And you'll have two different vertical chains (one for each column):

- parent <--> `imageButton` <--> `imageButton2` <--> `imageButton4` <--> parent
- parent <--> `imageButton1` <--> `imageButton3` <--> `imageButton5` <--> parent

Here's the xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cool"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/attitude"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/love"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/broken"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/funnn"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sad"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```